# Unable to designate CSV column heads "as.factor" for R -Error

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am having an issue with assigning factors to my data CSV. Here is a summary of the data frame:

```
> data.frame':  303 obs. of  12 variables:
> PLOT                : int  19 177 54 114 41 48 142 134 160 267 ...
> RANGE               : int  2 12 4 8 3 4 10 9 11 18 ...
> ROW                 : int  4 12 9 9 11 3 7 14 10 12 ...
> REP                 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> ENTRY               : Factor w/ 184 levels "","17_YMG_0293",..: 40 40 77 82 87 88 102 103 103 6 ...
> PLOT_ID             : Factor w/ 301 levels "","18_HZG_OvOv_001",..: 20 178 55 115 42 49 143 135 161 268 ...
> Shatter             : num  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 ...
> Chaff.Color         : Factor w/ 4 levels "","*Blank ones are segregating in color",..: 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 3 ...
> Heading_d.from.Jan.1: int  138 139 137 133 135 135 133 137 135 136 ...
> Height_cm           : int  74 73 77 76 74 79 78 73 76 70 ...
> Plot.weight..kg.    : num  0.26 0.18 0.19 0.14 0.33 0.19 0.13 0.11 0.24 0.18 ...
```

But I get this error:

```
HAYSData$Rep<-as.factor(HAYSData$Rep)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Rep, value = integer(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 303
```

I get the same type of error for Entry, Range, and Rows. I am not sure when I look at `length(Entry)` for example I get 300. I even tested with changing factor to numeric but it does not help.

I don't have an `NA` in my data each category is its own column as well.

I don't know if something is wrong with my CSV. I have worked this same script with another CSV but no issues in the part of the script for the other data.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's case-sensitive, try with:

```
HAYSData$REP <- as.factor(HAYSData$REP)
HAYSData$ENTRY <- as.factor(HAYSData$ENTRY)
HAYSData$RANGE <- as.factor(HAYSData$RANGE)
HAYSData$ROW <- as.factor(HAYSData$ROW)
```